# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting following error in my code

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setLocationrepo' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'locationRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Not a managed type: class com.logan.location.entities.Location

This is my repository Interface

```
package com.logan.location.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.logan.location.entities.Location;

@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer> {

}
```

This is my Service Interface

```
package com.logan.location.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.logan.location.entities.Location;

@Service
public interface LocationService {
    Location saveLocation(Location location);
    Location updateLocation(Location location);
    void deleteLocation(Location location);
    Location getLocationById(int id);
    List<Location> getAllLocations();
}
```

This is my serviceImpl

```
package com.logan.location.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.logan.location.entities.Location;
import com.logan.location.repos.LocationRepository;

@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {

    private LocationRepository locationrepo;
    @Autowired
    public void setLocationrepo(LocationRepository locationrepo) {
        this.locationrepo = locationrepo;
    }

    public Location saveLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locationrepo.save(location);
    }


    public Location updateLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locationrepo.save(location);
    }


    public void deleteLocation(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationrepo.delete(location);
    }


    public Location getLocationById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locationrepo.findById(id).get();
    }


    public List<Location> getAllLocations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locationrepo.findAll();
    }


    public LocationRepository getLocationrepo() {
        return locationrepo;
    }
}
```

And this is my entity Class

```
package com.logan.location.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

This is the starter class

```
package com.logan.location;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EntityScan("com.logan.location.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.logan.location.repos"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class LocationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LocationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It is showing my location entity class is unmanaged ,I have tried various answers but its not working ,any help??

Comment: Remove `@EntityScan` and remove `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: Doesnt works @M.Deinum

Comment: Do you mess around with `@Configuration` classes yourself?

Comment: I didnt get you?? @M.Deinum

Comment: Doyou have classes annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: yes I have @ Service and @ Repository  @M.Deinum

Comment: How is `@Service` / `@Repository` an `@Configuration` annotation?

Comment: no i dont have that

Comment: could not reproduce ur error. ur code running fine without adding entityscan and enablejparepositories

Comment: @LOGAN nothing seems wrong with the solution provided here. I even transformed your code in a simple application and everything seems to be working. Does your project contain other classes that you didn't add to the question ? Like another `@Configuration` class? @m-denium already asked you about about this. Did you have other classes that you deleted ? Then please run a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@Repository` annotation before LocationRepository. There is no need to add it.

```
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer> {
}
```

Also remove `@EntityScan("com.logan.location.entities")` and `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.logan.location.repos"})`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LocationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LocationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Add location repository bean like this:

```
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {

    private LocationRepository locationrepo;

    public LocationServiceImpl(LocationRepository locationrepo){
        this.locationrepo = locationrepo;
    }
}
```

Try with this.

Comment: The `LocationRepository` is injected through a setter, which is perfectly fine. Better would be to use constructor injection over field (or setter) injection as it is a required dependency.

Comment: yes its will be good autowired by constructor. code updating.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer. You didn't explain why the application didn't work in the first place, and even though, your code is running, you mainly transformed what @M.Deinum and myself explained in the comments.
It is good to take advantage of the full capabilities of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation contained in the `@SpringBootApplication`, but what you did here is mainly optimization, not a solution

Answer (score -4):

Please add `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` annotations in your `LocationApplication` class. And also you are missing the `@Column` annotaions in the entity class as well and please autowire the service properly.

```
@Autowired 
private LocationRepository locationrepo;
```

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`. Next to that the repository is auto wired through the setter. And `@Column` annotations aren't mandatory.

Comment: In addition to what @m-deinum said, the `@Column` annotation is not mandatory.